# Error on hive query: Invalid function MOD

Tags: hive, hiveql, hue

I need to create a View on HIVE by converting a query from Oracle, but I'm getting an error when running the query.

Here is the error message from HUE:

**Error while compiling statement: FAILED:SemanticException [Error 10011]:Invalid function MOD**

Here is a sample of my query:

```
 CREATE VIEW crp_db_name.v_new_view (
 OAA_ID COMMENT ' r',
 DT_RF COMMENT '  ',
 OAR_CD COMMENT ' ',
 AAAA COMMENT '  ',
 BBBB COMMENT '  ',
 CCCCC COMMENT ' ',
 DDDD COMMENT '',
 EEEE COMMENT ' ',
 FFFF COMMENT '',
 GGGG COMMENT '  ',
 HHHHH COMMENT '  ',
 IIII COMMENT ' ',
 JJJJ COMMENT ' ',
 KKKK COMMENT ' ',
 LLLLL COMMENT '  ',
 MMMM COMMENT '  ',
 NNNN COMMENT '  ',
 OOOO COMMENT '  ',
 RA_CD COMMENT '  ',
 RA_NM COMMENT '  ',
 RA_GGGG COMMENT '  ',
 RA_HHHHH COMMENT '  ',
 PPPP COMMENT '  ',
 QQQQ COMMENT ' ',
 RRRRR COMMENT ' ',
 SSSSS COMMENT ' ',
 TTTTT COMMENT ' ',
 UUUUU COMMENT ' ',
 VVVVV COMMENT ' ',
 WWWW COMMENT ' ',
 XXXXX COMMENT ' ',
 YYYYY COMMENT ' ',
 ZZZZZ COMMENT ' ',
 AQAQAQA COMMENT ' ',
 SWSWSWS COMMENT ' ',
 FRFRFRFFR COMMENT ' '
 ) COMMENT ' '
 AS 
  SELECT OA.EA_ID AS OAA_ID,
           OA.DT_RF,
           OA.ER_CD AS OAR_CD,
           OA.AAAA,
           DTST.BBBB,
           TR.CCCCC,
           OA.DDDD,
           OA.EEEE,
           OA.FFFF,
           OA.GGGG,
           OA.HHHHH,
           OA.IIII,
           OA.JJJJ,
           OA.KKKK,
           OA.LLLLL,
           OA.MMMM,
           OA.NNNN,
           OA.OOOO,
           CASE 
              WHEN OA.DDDD IN ('G1', 'G2')
              THEN
                 OA.ER_CD
              WHEN OA.DDDD = 'G3'
              THEN
                 CASE
                    WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T1M'
                    THEN
                       CASE
                          WHEN OA.ZZZZZ = 'HOST'
                          THEN
                             OA.ER_CD
                          ELSE
                             OA.KKKK
                       END
                    ELSE                            
                       CASE
                          WHEN OA.AQAQAQA = 'HOST'
                          THEN
                             OA.ER_CD
                          ELSE
                             OA.KKKK
                       END
                 END
              WHEN OA.DDDD = 'G4'
              THEN
                 OA.KKKK
           END
              AS RA_CD,
           CASE
              WHEN OA.DDDD IN ('G1', 'G2')
              THEN
                 OA.FFFF
              WHEN OA.DDDD = 'G3'
              THEN
                 CASE
                    WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T1M'
                    THEN
                       CASE
                          WHEN OA.ZZZZZ = 'HOST' THEN OA.FFFF
                          ELSE OA.LLLLL
                       END
                    ELSE
                       CASE
                          WHEN OA.AQAQAQA = 'HOST' THEN OA.FFFF
                          ELSE OA.LLLLL
                       END
                 END
              WHEN OA.DDDD = 'G4'
              THEN
                 OA.LLLLL
           END
              AS RA_NM,
           CASE
              WHEN OA.DDDD IN ('G1', 'G2')
              THEN
                 OA.GGGG
              WHEN OA.DDDD = 'G3'
              THEN
                 CASE
                    WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T1M'
                    THEN
                       CASE
                          WHEN OA.ZZZZZ = 'HOST' THEN OA.GGGG
                          ELSE OA.MMMM
                       END
                    ELSE
                       CASE
                          WHEN OA.AQAQAQA = 'HOST' THEN OA.GGGG
                          ELSE OA.MMMM
                       END
                 END
              WHEN OA.DDDD = 'G4'
              THEN
                 OA.MMMM
           END
              AS RA_GGGG,
           CASE
              WHEN OA.DDDD IN ('G1', 'G2')
              THEN
                 OA.HHHHH
              WHEN OA.DDDD = 'G3'
              THEN
                 CASE
                   WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T1M'
                    THEN
                       CASE
                          WHEN OA.ZZZZZ = 'HOST' THEN OA.HHHHH
                          ELSE OA.NNNN
                       END
                    ELSE
                       CASE
                          WHEN OA.AQAQAQA = 'HOST' THEN OA.HHHHH
                          ELSE OA.NNNN
                       END
                 END
              WHEN OA.DDDD = 'G4'
              THEN
                 OA.NNNN
           END
              AS RA_HHHHH,
           CASE
              WHEN OA.VVVVV = 1
              THEN                                            
                 CASE
                    WHEN OA.IIII = 1
                    THEN
                       CASE
                          WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T2Q' THEN 'ITS + 15th WD'
                          ELSE 'RD + 30th WD'
                       END
                    ELSE                         
                       CASE
                          WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T2Q' THEN 'ITS + 20th WD'
                          ELSE 'RD + 35th WD'
                       END
                 END
              ELSE             
                 '-99'
           END
              AS PPPP,
           CASE
              WHEN OA.VVVVV = 1              
              THEN
                 CASE
                    WHEN MOD (OA.DT_RF, 100) IN (3,
                                                    6,
                                                    9,
                                                    12)
                    THEN
                       1
                    ELSE
                       CASE WHEN OA.WWWW = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                 END                                         

                ELSE            
                  0
           END
              AS QQQQ,
           CASE
              WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T1M' THEN NVL (DTST.AZAZAZZA, 0)
              WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T2M' THEN NVL (DTST.GHGHGHGH, 0)
              WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T2Q' THEN NVL (DTST.TYTYTYTY, 0)
              ELSE 0
           END
              AS RRRRR,
           CASE
              WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T1M'
              THEN
                 NVL (DTST.PLPLPLPLP, 0)
              WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T2M'
              THEN
                 NVL (DTST.OUOIUOIUOI, 0)
              WHEN TR.CCCCC = 'T2Q'
              THEN
                 NVL (DTST.RIRORIRORI, 0)
              ELSE
                 0
           END
              AS SSSSS,
           OA.TTTTT,
           CASE
              WHEN     OA.VVVVV <> 1
                   AND ( (  NVL (DTST.AZAZAZZA, 0)
                          + NVL (DTST.GHGHGHGH, 0)
                          + NVL (DTST.TYTYTYTY, 0)
                          + NVL (DTST.PLPLPLPLP, 0)
                          + NVL (DTST.OUOIUOIUOI, 0)
                          + NVL (DTST.RIRORIRORI, 0)) > 0)
              THEN
                 1
              ELSE
                 0
           END
              AS UUUUU,  
           OA.VVVVV,
           OA.WWWW,
           OA.XXXXX,
           OA.YYYYY,
           OA.ZZZZZ,
           OA.AQAQAQA,
           OA.SWSWSWS,
           CASE
              WHEN TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'yyyymmdd')) >
                      OA.SWSWSWS
              THEN
                 'TRUE'
              ELSE
                 'FALSE'

END
              AS FRFRFRFFR
      FROM  crp_db_name.A_D_OBSRVD_AGNT_BY_DT_RF OA


JOIN  crp_db_name.A_ADM_CCCCC TR
              ON (IND_UNQ_MNTH = 1
                     AND MOD (OA.DT_RF, 100) = TR.MNTH_NMBR)
           LEFT OUTER JOIN  crp_db_name.A_ADM_RD_OA_DTST DTST
              ON (OA.EA_ID = DTST.OAA_ID
                     AND OA.DT_RF = DTST.DT_RF);
```

The query is quite long and I'm not sure which exactly causes the error.

Comment: I think you need to change lot of statements, data type mismatching issues before ensuring you have a working query - like you need to modify  `TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'yyyymmdd')` as per hive. MOD() works in hive like oracle so shouldnt be any issue.

Comment: @KoushikRoy Good catch on the SYSDATE part. Thank you so much! Regarding the MOD, I changed it to PMOD which looks like helped a little. I still have a new issue but it's just related to the missing table.

Comment: Pls modify your qn if youre still facing any issue